# Creating new table from existing table + most recent date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, powerbi

I have a table that has ID, VALUE, DATE in PowerBI connected from an SQL table. A single ID has several dates and I only want the most recent. In PowerBI, I've tried Lastdate and Max to get the most recent date but no luck.

So now I'm trying to filter this directly in SQL. So, would I have to create a new table from my existing table, because from my understanding you cant really edit an SQL table permanently? Besides I think it'd good to still keep the original table.

So, how do I go about creating a new table that gets the most recent date from another table?

Thanks

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: @DaleK I have added as much detail as I can, I dont know what more I can add

Comment: As stated, **sample data**, **desired results** and an**attempt** based on your research.

Comment: And confirm you are interested in SQL Server not MySQL - you'll note that someone provided an answer based on the original MySQL tag, so you've wasted their time assuming its SQL Server you are interested in.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need another table. You can do this in SQL as a `SELECT` query using the `row_number()` function. It will look something like this:

```
SELECT <columns>
FROM (
    SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) rn
   FROM [tablename]
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: I forgot to add the filter will need to be permanent - does this query still apply?

Comment: Yes, it will work.

Answer (score -1):

First of all I'm not into PowerBI but since you need to work with the SQL side I think this can help.

Create the table (the name is up to you) with the same cols if you don't want to work around. (remember to set the ID to PK so it doesn't allow duplicates, this will become handy).

Then you must create a trigger that after insert on the original table try to insert it into the copy table. Something like this (on your trigger definition).

```
INSERT INTO copyTable (id,value,date) 
VALUES (1,'Normal',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, value='Normal'
```

After that every time you insert a new row on your original table the trigger will do the work of copying that row to the copy table.

Again I'm not sure about how PowerBI selects from a database but this is the workaround if you want to create another table.